# Need help finding the fundamental set of solutions to the differential equation: $y^{(6)}+y=cos(t)$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I factor it to $(r^2+1)(r^4-r^2+1)$. Then I sub $x=r^2$ to get $(x^2-x+1)$. The roots I am getting aren't correct and I'm not sure if I should be subbing the second polynomial like how I did or not.

Comment: The whole thing. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You also don't have a differential equation as you wrote it

Comment: What do you mean @Brenton

Comment: @PeterPol Differential equations involve a function and its derivative. But there is no derivative in your equation.

Comment: y^6 is the sixth derivative?

Comment: @PeterPol Oh, typically for clarity, you should write it as $y^{(6)}(t)$

Comment: I tried to, but I'm still new to the formatting and it wouldn't raise it to (6) so I just let it 6, sorry about that.

Comment: Write it as y^{(6)} - it comes out as $y^{(6)}$.

Comment: @martycohen thank you

Comment: The roots of $r^6+1=0$ are those twelfth roots of unity that aren't also sixth roots. In other words $r=e^{k\pi i/6}$ with $k=1,3,5,7,9,11$. With $k=3$ you get $r=i$, and with $k=9$ you get $r=-i$. The other zeros are of order twelve.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you, that makes more sense.

Comment: @Moo yes I did, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Wolfy says
y(t) = c_5 sin(t) + c_4 e^(-(sqrt(3) t)/2) sin(t/2) + c_6 e^((sqrt(3) t)/2) sin(t/2) + c_1 e^((sqrt(3) t)/2) cos(t/2) + c_2 cos(t) + c_3 e^(-(sqrt(3) t)/2) cos(t/2) + 1/6 t sin(t).

I entered it as
y''''''+y=cos(t).

Comment: I know the answer. I'm trying to figure out how to find the fundamental set of solutions. I can't figure them out like I usually can.